# Current Mode Control

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, converter

I am referring the doc https://www.venableinstruments.com/current-mode-control-wp and trying to understand behavior of current mode control but unable to understand following things

1.[image]

What is the slope used in the practical design is it -m or -m/2?
" **-m slope gives rejection of disturbances in first cycle itself**" what disturbances is trying to refer and how it is rejection in first cycle itself?

[image]

Can anyone please explain the highlighted yellow statements ,not able to understand completely lost here .Thanks.

Comment: This paper seems to be made by copy/pasting the original application note [U-97](https://www.thierry-lequeu.fr/data/U-97.pdf) published by Barney Holland. At that time, sub-harmonic oscillations could not be mathematically justified and all sort of models were built to justify the observations. The best is to resort to sampled data analysis as Dr. Ray Ridley did in his 1990 thesis. You can check my [paper](http://www.how2power.com/newsletters/2101/articles/H2PToday2101_design_ONSemi.pdf?NOREDIR=1) and follow the links in the reference to gain more knowledge on the subject.